# Runge Kutta with boundary condition at infinity?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

So I'm trying to numerically solve a second order ODE of the form:

$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = nx + \frac{C}{t}$

But there are two… complicated boundary conditions.

$\lim_{t\to0} = 0$

$\lim_{t\to\infty} = 0$

I've set up some code for RK4. Essentially, I've been setting my initial values as $t = 0.000001$, $x=0.000001$ then evaluating up to some really large number and checking if that's close enough to 0. Then I've been testing random combinations of $\frac{dx}{dt}\rvert_{t=0}$ and $n$, but I'm not sure that this is the right approach.

What is typically done for these sorts of conditions?

Comment: The derivative of the exact solution is unbounded at $t=0$, and $x\leq0$ for all $t\geq0$. So the simple approach you describe (which is often fine) won't work. I tried adding a small number to the $t$ so you don't have $C/0$ initially, but it didn't help.

Comment: What do you mean it’s unbound at infinity? This equation comes from a simplified version of the Shrodinger equation for an electron around a hydrogen atom. The probability of finding an electron as radius approaches infinity most certainly does go to 0, so im not sure what you mean.

Comment: Sorry I read that wrong! Yeah, there’s weird stuff going on at 0 since the electron can never really be exactly where the proton is! So yeah this is a problem...